# Flutter file_picker compress image quality

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to change the quality of an image on file_picker package?

Here is my code:

```
void pickMedia() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
    );
    if(result == null) return;

    PlatformFile? file = result.files.first;

    viewFile(file);
  }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: You can use `'package:image/image.dart'`. It has `.encodeJpg` method where you can set quality.

Answer (score 0):

use lib image_picker:
link : https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

**Code:**

```
final result = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: yourQuality);
```